# Gerrit review not found in spite of present in DB

Tags: mysql, indexing, gerrit

We are using **Gerrit 2.12** with **MySQL** DB. There is one review open for a while but when I try to access it from Gerrit UI, I get following error.

> The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page.

I am logged into the UI and my account have administrative capabilities.I can see the entry of the change in `changes` table in data base. Should reindexing solve the problem? I am more curious about what was the trigger for disappearance of change in UI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have verified if the changes were there in the repository by cloning the corresponding change under `refs/changes` branch.

As the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#change-ref) says, When a commit is pushed for review, Gerrit stores it in a staging area which is a branch in the special `refs/changes/` namespace. A change ref has the format `refs/changes/XX/YYYY/ZZ` where `YYYY` is the numeric change number, `ZZ` is the patch set number and `XX` is the last two digits of the numeric change number, e.g. `refs/changes/20/884120/1`. Understanding the format of this ref is not required for working with Gerrit.

Using the change ref, git clients can fetch the corresponding commit, e.g. for local verification.

```
git clone <URL>
cd <reponame>
git fetch https://yourhostname/reponame refs/changes/16/261016/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

If you find the fetch to be happening successful, it means that the change is present and therefore a full reindex as the appropriate user should fix.

```
su gerrit -c "java -jar gerrit.war reindex"
```

PS. [Online reindex](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.2/cmd-index-start.html) did not help in my case. I had to do a full offline reindex as above.